# generate model from database with multischema

Tags: grails-orm

im trying to generate the model using the tool. but in my case i have more than 1 schema and the app crash.

g.UseDB(db) // reuse your gorm db

g.ApplyBasic(
// Generate struct `User` based on table `users`
// g.GenerateModel("area"),
// Generate all tables multischema

g.GenerateAllTable(),

Anyone with this issue?

[error] generate struct from table fail: mssql: Invalid object name 'payment_card'.
panic: generate struct fail

goroutine 1 [running]:
gorm.io/gen.(*Generator).GenerateModelAs(0x14000326ff0, {0x140000103d0, 0xc}, {0x140005a8f70?, 0x1330?}, {0x0?, 0x104f97b01?, 0x14000364100?})
/Users/gcortinez/Projects/go-projects/gogen/vendor/gorm.io/gen/generator.go:118 +0x230
gorm.io/gen.(*Generator).GenerateModel(0x14000326ff0, {0x140000103d0, 0xc}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
/Users/gcortinez/Projects/go-projects/gogen/vendor/gorm.io/gen/generator.go:110 +0x70
gorm.io/gen.(*Generator).GenerateAllTable(0x14000326ff0, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
/Users/gcortinez/Projects/go-projects/gogen/vendor/gorm.io/gen/generator.go:141 +0x13c
main.main()
/Users/gcortinez/Projects/go-projects/gogen/main.go:46 +0x168